# Chaining pytest fixtures

Tags: python, pytest

I'm looking to be able to setup my tests to combine multiple fixtures into a single fixture - or inversely filter fixtures from another fixture. For example:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
def number(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture()
def odd_number(number):
    if number % 2 == 1:
        return number
    else:
        return None  # Skip (or some kid of filter)

def test_all_positive(number):  # want to be called with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6
    assert number >= 0

def test_all_odds_positive(odd_number):  # want to be called with 1, 3, and 5
    assert odd_number >= 0
```

This is clearly not the the way `pytest` expects me to get the effect I want the `odd_number` fixture being passed into `test_all_odds_positive` to not include `None`s.

Comment: The code has per se issues... no imports, make_shapes() missing, problems invalid syntax. As it stands, there is nothing to reproduce.

Comment: It wasn't intended to be run directly. It was more pseudo code to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. If the problem doesn't make sense through that example I can try and reword it or come up with a clearer example.

Comment: Yes, please. Makes little sense or I'm too dumb to get the idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hopefully that makes a little more sense @IgnacioVergaraKausel . Let me know if not.

Comment: Ok, now it's much better and understandable. I'm not aware of `pytest` being able to do what you try to achieve. My approach would be to use `@pytest.mark.parametrize' and handle there the filter. Alternatively, you could build a decorator that injects the filtered elements into the fixture.

Comment: I did find this https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization-with-multiple-fixtures while checking the documentation, perhaps you get some inspiration.

Comment: I did indeed inspire me, thank you. I've replaced the line `return None` with `pytest.skip('not odd')`. I'm not convinced this is the intended use case of but it's significantly better from where I was. If you want to post that as an answer I can give you credit @IgnacioVergaraKausel

Comment: No, you should answer your question yourself ;)

Comment: I will probably keep this open a few days then to see if there's a better way. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Could you extract the filtering outside the fixtures?

```py
import pytest

numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

@pytest.fixture(params=numbers)
def number(request):
    return request.param

def odd_numbers(ns):
    return [n for n in ns if n % 2 == 1]

@pytest.fixture(params=odd_numbers(numbers))
def odd_number(request):
    return request.param

def test_all_positive(number):  # want to be called with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6
    assert number >= 0

def test_all_odds_positive(odd_number):  # want to be called with 1, 3, and 5
    assert odd_number >= 0
```

```
collected 10 items                                                                                         

foo.py::test_all_positive[0] PASSED                                                                  [ 10%]
foo.py::test_all_positive[1] PASSED                                                                  [ 20%]
foo.py::test_all_positive[2] PASSED                                                                  [ 30%]
foo.py::test_all_positive[3] PASSED                                                                  [ 40%]
foo.py::test_all_positive[4] PASSED                                                                  [ 50%]
foo.py::test_all_positive[5] PASSED                                                                  [ 60%]
foo.py::test_all_positive[6] PASSED                                                                  [ 70%]
foo.py::test_all_odds_positive[1] PASSED                                                             [ 80%]
foo.py::test_all_odds_positive[3] PASSED                                                             [ 90%]
foo.py::test_all_odds_positive[5] PASSED                                                             [100%]

============================================ 10 passed in 0.01s ============================================
```