# pytest - combine fixtures into one fixture

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I would like to have three fixtures. They are used to setup configurations for tests, and specify which tests use which configurations.

The three fixtures should be:
release_configs
dev_configs
all_configs

If a test uses the fixture "all_configs", it will be tested for each config session run.
If a test uses the fixture "dev_configs", it will be tested only for some subset.
If a test uses the fixture "release_configs", it will be tested only for some other subset.

all_configs contains the sum of dev and release.

Is this possible?

Here is what I have for all_configs:

```
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=False, scope="session", params=release_configs_to_test+dev_configs_to_test, ids=release_configs_to_test+dev_configs_to_test)
    def all_configs(self, request):
        name = request.param
        print('config fixture called')
        self._setup_config(name)
        yield name
```

Where release_configs_to_test and dev_configs_to_test are just lists of string (name of the config)

EDIT:

Seems like a similar problem to [Chaining pytest fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696002/chaining-pytest-fixtures) which is unsolved.

However, this question is trying to filter fixtures, while I am attempting to combine them.

Either option would be workable, however.

Answer (score 0):

Pytest fixtures can "request" other fixtures, which can be used to combine, filter, or otherwise process.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#fixtures-can-request-other-fixtures

```
# Arrange
@pytest.fixture
def first_entry():
    return "a"


# Arrange
@pytest.fixture
def order(first_entry):
    return [first_entry]


def test_string(order):
    # Act
    order.append("b")

    # Assert
    assert order == ["a", "b"]
```